# In SQL, how can we match using LIKE up to but not exceeding a number of wildcard characters?

Tags: sql, sqlite

E.g. in regex, we can use {n,m} to specify that we want to match the previous element at least n times, but no more than m times.

Is there a way to do this in SQL (specifically sqlite) whereby we match a wildcard '_' up to 5 times but no more?

E.g. I want up to 5 characters between the letters j and z

So I would get Jaz or Jaaaaaz but not Jaaaaaaz

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you could just use

```
WHERE col LIKE 'J%z' AND LENGTH(col) < 8
```

e.g.

```
SELECT 'Jaaaz' LIKE 'J%z' AND LENGTH('Jaaaz') < 8, 'Jaaaaaaz' LIKE 'J%z' AND LENGTH('Jaaaaaaz') < 8
```

Output

```
1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a regexp module into SQLite.  That is probably the best solution to your problem.

You can do what you want as:

```
where col not like '______'  -- 6 underscores
```

Or, more simply:

```
when length(col) < 6
```

That is the direct answer to your question.

EDIT:

For up to five characters, you can do:

```
where col like 'j%z' and
      col not like 'j______z'
```

Or use the more brute force:

```
where col like 'jz' or
      col like 'j_z' or
      col like 'j__z' or
      col like 'j___z' or
      col like 'j____z' or
      col like 'j_____z'
```

If you want these patterns within a string (rather than the whole string), then include `%` at the beginning and end of the pattern.

Comment: It'd have to be `not like '%______%'` because the LIKE predicate implicitly matches the whole string, unlike regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Bill.
I edited my question to be more clear. 
I am looking for between 0 and 5 wildcards between a series of characters. 

E.g. I want up to 5 characters between the letters j and z

So I would get Jaz or Jaaaaaz but not Jaaaaaaz